ERROR: javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory cannot be created when i use compile 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3' in gradle
i got this error when i use compile 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3' in my build.gradle.
The error class is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class es.juntadeandalucia.educacion.becas.reintegros.XMLHelper and i think the problematic line is:
public static SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

the complete error is:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory cannot be created
    ....
    ....
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory: Provider org.iso_relax.verifier.jaxp.validation.RELAXNGSchemaFactoryImpl could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    ....
    ....
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/iso_relax/verifier/VerifierConfigurationException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        ....
        ....
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.iso_relax.verifier.VerifierConfigurationException

i try using the library 'org.jopendocument:isorelax-jaxp-bridge-ILM:1.1' and put the system property System.setProperty( "javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory", XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI);
none of them works. thanks
